# Check if line in file contains a pattern in Bash

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to figure out why this wont check the lines in the file and echo
How do you compare or check if strings contain something?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do 
    #if the line ends 
    if [[ "$line" == '*Bye$' ]] 
    then
    :
        #if the line ends 
    elif [[ "$line" == '*Fly$' ]] 
    then
        echo "\*\*\*"$line"\*\*\*"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `*Bye$` is not a shell pattern (shell patterns don't use the `$` notation, they just use the *lack* of a trailing `*`) — and even if it were, putting it in single-quotes would disable it. Instead, just write:

```
    if [[ "$line" == *Bye ]]
```

(and similarly for `Fly`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use *proper* regular expressions, that's done with the `=~` operator, such as:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ Bye$ ]]
```

The limited regular expressions you get from shell patterns with `==` don't include things like the end-line marker `$`.

Note that you can do something this simple with shell patterns (`*Bye`) but, if you want the full power of regular expressions (or even just a consistent notation), `=~` is the way to go.

Comment: Putting `^.*` at the beginning of a regular expression changes its meaning not at all.

Comment: @Mark, you're absolutely right, but that has nothing to do with either the question or answer. It's just a sample regex value for testing. However, I'll change it to avoid any unnecessary discussion.